# Slick way to create nested array types

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have something like this:

```
const rhs = ['Foo.Bar', 'Two', 'Three'];
```

and I want to get:

```
Array<Foo.Bar<Two<Three>>>
```

I have this which works:

```
       const literalType = rhs.reduce((a,b) => {
                    return [a,'<',b].join('');
                });

       const withBraces = literalType.concat(
            new Array(rhs.length).fill(null).join('>')
       );

       const finalVal = `Array<${withBraces}>`,
```

But I am looking for something a little slicker than that. Does anyone have a good idea on how to make this simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining two of the other answers, you can use [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get something "slick":

```js
const rhs = ['Foo.Bar', 'Two', 'Three'];
const finalVal = `Array${rhs.reduceRight((a, b) => `<${b}${a}>`, '')}`;

console.log(finalVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Array.reduce" like below to achieve this

```js
const rhs = ['Foo.Bar', 'Two', 'Three'];

let res = rhs.reduce((s, d, i) => 
      (s += '<' + d
        , i == rhs.length -1 && (s += ('>'.repeat(i+1)))
        , s) 
      , 'Array')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) which helps in going "outwards" in this case:

```js
const rhs = ['Foo.Bar', 'Two', 'Three'];

const res = 'Array' + rhs.reduceRight((a, c) => `<${c + a}>`, '');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just reverse the array and build from the inside instead of the outside, then it's easier, see:

```
const literalType = rhs.reverse().reduce((a,b) => {
    return [b,'<',a, '>'].join('');
});

const finalVal = `Array<${literalType}>`,
```

Comment: `reduceRight` is also a function, and won't modify the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const rhs = ['Foo.Bar', 'Two', 'Three'];

const r = `Array<${rhs.reduce((r,c,i,a) => 
   `${r}<${c}`.concat(i == a.length-1 ? '>'.repeat(i) : ''))}>`

console.log(r)
```

The idea is to use the [**ES6 template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) hydration with [**`Array.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) since that method provides convenient access to the array `index` and the actual `array` internally.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use simple constructs like,

```
  str = "Array<" + rhs.join("<") + (">".repeat(rhs.length))
    console.log(str)
```

Alternately, for empty array we can prepend first part "Array<" conditionally